How to get rid of the small media player box on top left of screen with video area selection in VLC?
When I open up a video in the VLC media player, it automatically has a little box on the top left of the screen. It's like a miniature video player with a box I can drag around the area to focus the main larger screen. And it's still there when in fullscreen.
How do I get rid of this so I can just play my video normally without that little box?

Welcome to Superuser! What operating system are you using?

I don't have such a box. Could you add a screenshot?

This might be the Interactive Zoom feature in VLC.
You can toggle it using Tools > Effects and Filters > Video Effects > Geometry > Interactive Zoom.


+1 Good find. That's probably it.
